# How do I read the state of 3 output pins on an Arduino UNO and then NAND them together?

Tags: arduino, proteus

So I am working on software to control a H8 inverter. I got code that does SPWM for a 3 phase inverter online. I then applied a software NAND gate on 3 outputs from the Arduino UNO and this is the result I got:
[image: Result of applying a software NAND gate on 3 outputs from the Arduino UNO]

and this:
[image: Result of applying a software NAND gate on 3 outputs from the Arduino UNO]

I used a hardware NAND gate and I got this:
[image: Result of applying a hardware NAND gate on 3 outputs from the Arduino UNO]

```
//-------www<electronics-project-hub>com--------//
#include <math.h>
int Output1 = 11;
int Output2 = 10;
int Output3 = 9;

int Output4 = 6;

int potVal = 0;
float A = 0;
float B = 0.104;
int Freq_IN = A0;
int var1 = 0;
int var2 = 0;
int var3 = 0;
int var4 = 0;
int var5 = 0;
int var6 = 0;
float Phase1 = 2 * PI / 3;
float Phase2 = 4 * PI / 3;
float Phase3 = 2 * PI;
boolean toggle = true; // true = Enabling Serial Plotter Output
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Output1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Output2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Output3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Freq_IN, INPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  A += B;
 analogWrite(Output1, var1);
 analogWrite(Output2, var2);
 analogWrite(Output3, var3);

 digitalWrite(Output4,!(digitalRead(Output1)&&digitalRead(Output2)&&digitalRead(Output3)));

 if (toggle == true)
 {
    Serial.print(var1);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(var2);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(var3);
 }
 var4 = 126 * sin(A + Phase1);
 var1 = var4 + 128;
 var5 = 126 * sin(A + Phase2);
 var2 = var5 + 128;
 var6 = 126 * sin(A + Phase3);
 var3 = var6 + 128;
 if (A >= 2 * PI)
 {
    A = 0;
 }
 potVal = analogRead(Freq_IN);
 delay(potVal);
}
//-------www<electronics-project-hub>com--------//
```

I would like to point out that the software NAND output stayed ON all the time. The hardware NAND output varied, which is the result I am trying to get.

Comment: Your "software NAND" is simply not fast enough to keep up with the PWM signals while also doing complex floating point calculations. You need to rethink this, or use a hardware NAND gate.

Comment: @StarCat How do I make it fast enough? What part of the code represents complex floating point calculations?

Comment: Fast enough for what? You haven't really explained what your code is supposed to do. The floating point calculations are, for the most part, the `sin()` calculations. Every single `sin()` takes hundreds of microseconds on an Arduino (Uno?), making your `loop()` take probably the better part of a millisecond. The smallest peak on your output is (about) 40 microseconds, so you do the math. I think you need to pre-calculate your sine values and/or ditch the floating point altogether to have any chance of doing what you want to do in software on an Arduino.

Comment: @StarCat the original code is supposed to generate sine waves for a 3 phase inverter. I am trying to modify the code to control a H8 inverter.

Comment: Yes, but what do you need Output4 for? Can you see that the PWM is running independent of your loop and that your && operation will be very hit and miss - mostly miss by the look of things.

Comment: Maybe you can explain (in your question) what your H8 inverter needs to control it and why you need the NANDed signal. You could generate your own PWM timing from a timer interrupt and generate the NAND output from inside that ISR.